# How can I implement SSL HTTPS on XAMPP Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: laravel, apache, docker, ssl

Currently I've installed my `LaravelAPP` on ubuntu `18.04` LTS (docker instance)

1. In this `path: /opt/lampp/htdocs/api_tk`
2. In my `/opt/lampp/etc/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf` I have this working setup without `SSL enabled`

*PORT: 3021 is used for docker as port 80*

```
<VirtualHost *:3021>
DocumentRoot "/opt/lampp/htdocs/api_tk/public"
ServerName myapi.domain.com
ServerAlias myapi.domain.com

ErrorLog "logs/API-error_log"
CustomLog "logs/API-access_log" common
</VirtualHost>
```

3. And this setup is working fine I can use my `laravel api` very well.
4. After this setup I tried to generate `CSR` on my docker instance with a name of `request_myapi.csr`
5. So I tried to generate also a private key with a name of `private.key`
6. `private.key` is encrypted with something like this

   ```
   -----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
   Proc-Type: 4,ENCRYPTED
   DEK-Info: DES-EDE3-CBC,0C7820F5FAA4FF26

   Sometext.............

   -----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
   ```
7. So I tried to decrypt and I named it as `private_new.key`. This looks like:

   ```
    -----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----

    Some text....       

    -----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
   ```
8. The `csr` that I created was used to generate my `crt` files like this

   located at : `/opt/lampp/htdocs/ssl_key`

   - myapi-bundle.crt
   - myapi.crt
   - myapi.pem

     9. So I tried to use this site to check if my `private_new.key` and `myapi.crt` is matched.

https://www.sslshopper.com/certificate-key-matcher.html

[image]

10. So I updated my `httpd-vhosts.conf`

with ssl enabled

```
<VirtualHost *:3021>
DocumentRoot "/opt/lampp/htdocs/api_tk/public"
<Directory "/opt/lampp/htdocs/api_tk/public">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    AllowOverride All
    Order allow,deny
    allow from all
</Directory>
ServerName myapi.domain.com
ServerAlias myapi.domain.com

ErrorLog "logs/API-error_log"

SSLEngine on
SSLCertificateFile "/opt/lampp/htdocs/ssl_key/myapi.crt"
SSLCertificateKeyFile "/opt/lampp/htdocs/ssl_key/private_new.key"
SSLCACertificateFile "/opt/lampp/htdocs/ssl_key/myapi-bundle.crt"
Redirect permanent / https://myapi.domain.com

</VirtualHost>
```

11. and restart my xampp using this command `sudo /opt/lampp/lampp restart`

and gives me something like this

[image]

Seems like there's nothing wrong with my setup because it restarted properly and with ok status.

**12. So I tried to check if the `api` is ssl enabled already but seems like it didn't work is there anywrong with my setup?**

*Note: I already done with my laravel https setup like : routes & resources(css and js)*

Main Error: **refused to connect.**

[image]

[image]

Comment: Can you be more specific with "seems like it didn't work"? Do you get SSL errors? Browser warnings? Connection timeout/refused?

Comment: Sorry, my error on the browser is **refused to connect** the apache xampp doesn't give me any error. I updated my question and placed my error

Comment: Is that the full error message? Is it the browser refusing to connect to the server, or the server refusing the connection? Browsers sometimes block SSL connections to non-standard HTTPS ports (anything other than 443).

Comment: As I checked my API-error.log there's no error occured and also the browser says refused to connect. Check the error image on the updated question. On my docker instance port 3021 is used as 80. since I have multiple instances of docker. and I directly put the ssl config on port 3021

Comment: That error usually means that the host you are trying to connect to is not listening on the port that the connection was being opened on. Is docker forwarding port 443 on the host to the SSL port of your webserver inside the docker container? (assuming the URL in your address bar begins with HTTPS and there's no port in the address)

Comment: As of now, I didnt use port 443 in the host and in my docker container. I just simply configure the ssl configuration inside the docker instance. and it listens to 3021 as port 80 in the host. (My laravel url doesn't have port on the end of the url. I only browse the laravel using its own `myapi.domain.com`

Comment: In addition, I have multiple instances of docker such as : `3021, 3022, 3023` and I'm using the instance of `3021`. Do I need to do something with `httpd-ssl.conf?` or is it okay on `httpd-xampp.conf` to setup the ssl?

Comment: If your browser's address bar is `http://myapi.domain.com` then it will be connecting to port 80, but it won't be using the SSL protocol. If it begins with `https` without a port in the address (like `https://myapi.domain.com:3021`) then it will be connecting to port 443, not 80. Whatever the port is that your browser is trying to connect to, it seems like your host is not listening to that port. For example, you might need to start the container with something like `-p 443:3021`

Comment: I'll check on that for a moment. :)

Comment: Hello @TravisBritz I tried to do the 443 using 4021 tcp on my docker. What's the next step should I do?